# Fibonacci in recursive and normal fibonacci?

Tags: c#, recursion

So I have made 2 versions of Fibonacci calculator, one is in normal way and one is in recursion.

```
    public static int Fib(int n)
    {
        if (n == 0) { return 0; }
        if(n == 1) { return 1; }
        int a = 0;
        int b = 1;
        int res = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= n-1; i++)
        {
            res = a + b;
            a = b;
            b = res;

        }
        return res;
    }

    public static int FibRec(int n)
    {
        if((n == 0) || (n == 1)) { return n; }
        else
        {
            return FibRec(n-1) + FibRec(n-2);
        }
    }
```

When i run both the same time, the recursive version is incorrect.

```
static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Fib(7)); //return 21
        Console.WriteLine(FibRec(7)); //return 13
    }
```

I tried to check for a correct version ones on the internet but strangely all the answer is quite the same as mine. I'm very weak at recursive and I absolutely have no idea what wrong with, so I'd be very grateful if any expert can point out the problem.

Comment: What do you think should be the first value in the sequence? What should `n` be, in order to compute that value? The approach is generally correct, you just aren't using consistent definitions between the two implementations (and have possibly masked this by using, in one case, wrong values for the hard-coded answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop in `Fib` is incorrect in terms of the number of iterations - and this isn't helped by using non-descript names. `FibRec` is correct, contrary to your assertion in the question. Note that one way of determining that is to print out (say) the first 10 values of the sequence, which I'd expect to be 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34. That helps to find where the problem *starts*.

I would advice using `current` (as in, the current result) and `next` (the next number), and looping `n` times. That way you don't even need the base conditions, because it all just drops out. You also don't need to keep *three* variables outside the loop - you can just introduce a third variable inside the loop instead:

```cs
static int Fib(int n)
{
    int current = 0;
    int next = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int tmp = current + next;
        current = next;
        next = tmp;
    }
    return current;
}
```

Note that deconstruction assignment in modern C# allows you to write it even more clearly, reassigning both `current` and `next` in a single statement, based on the previous values:

```cs
static int Fib(int n)
{
    int current = 0;
    int next = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        (current, next) = (next, current + next);
    }
    return current;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> When i run both the same time, the recursive version is incorrect.

[Fibonacci(7) *is* 13](https://wolframalpha.com/input?i=F_7), so your recursive `FibRec` method is correct.

> I absolutely have no idea what wrong with

There is nothing wrong with it.

> I'd be very grateful if any expert can point out the problem.

There is no problem.

There are only some possible stylistic improvements: you could protect against a caller passing a negative number as an argument and you could use a guard clause or a conditional expression.

If you change the condition to `n <= 1` or `n < 2`, then `FibRec` will not run into an infinite loop if a caller passes a negative number. While that is an elegant way of solving the problem, `FibRec` will return a wrong result in that case. A better way would be to [`throw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/throw) an appropriate [`Exception`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.exception), in particular an [`ArgumentOutOfRangeException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.argumentoutofrangeexception) in that case:

```csharp
if (n < 0)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
        nameof(n),
        n,
        "Argument must be non-negative."
    );
```

Since `throw` terminates the method, there is no need for an `else`. The rest of the method will only be executed if the argument value is valid.

The same applies to `return`: if you `return` from the method, the rest of the method will not be executed, therefore, it is not necessary to wrap the rest of the method into an `else` branch:

```csharp
public static int FibRec(int n)
{
    if (n < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
            nameof(n),
            n,
            "Argument must be non-negative."
        );

    if (n < 2) return n;
    return FibRec(n-1) + FibRec(n-2);
}
```

This is sometimes called a [*guard clause*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_(computer_science)).

Alternatively, you could use a [*conditional expression*](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator):

```csharp
public static int FibRec(int n)
{
    if (n < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
            nameof(n),
            n,
            "Argument must be non-negative."
        );

    return n < 2 ? n : FibRec(n-1) + FibRec(n-2);
}
```

In your original version, where you had no error checking, you could then also use an [*expression-bodied method*](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members):

```csharp
public static int FibRec(int n) =>
    n < 2 ? n : FibRec(n-1) + FibRec(n-2);
```

But in this case, you lose the error checking.

See [this .NET Fiddle with all the different variants](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7Mo7f4).

Comment: Then there remains a corresponding question about the iterative code. But either way, the question could as well be considered to be caused by a typo.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: The OP *explicitly* asks about the recursive solution. They do not ask about the iterative one. Really, the iterative version is irrelevant to the question and could just be edited out.

Comment: Fair enough. The question should still be closed in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Your case base should return 1, not n

```
public static int FibRec(int n)
{
    if((n == 0) || (n == 1)) { return 1; }
    else
    {
        return FibRec(n-1) + FibRec(n-2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Given that both approaches give a starting sequence of 0 then 1, I'd assume that's the version the OP wants - 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5 etc. I believe that's the most conventional form of the sequence.

Comment: Just an advice, readability is very important. Functionally is the same, but it is better `if(n == 0 || n == 1)`